# STM32L053 I2C problems with LIS3DH sensor

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to recover the data from the LIS3DH sensor and I found [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1CIOUZdeR4).

In the tutorial the person uses the following to see if the sensor is ready for use:

```
if(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1,SLAVEI2C_ADD,10,100)==HAL_OK)
```

However when I make the connections and run the program, I don't see anything.

I connected the sensor as follows:

- Sensor -> STM32
- SDA -> SDA/D14 (Pull up 10kOhms)
- SCL -> SCL/D15 (Pull up 10kOhms)
- SDO -> 3.3v
- CS -> 3.3V
- GND -> GND
- Vcc -> 3.3v

The following code is the one I am using to try to know the status of my sensor.

```
#include "main.h"

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

#define SLAVEI2C_ADD 0x19

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
  MX_I2C1_Init()


  HAL_Delay(1000);
  if(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1,SLAVEI2C_ADD,10,100)==HAL_OK)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);
  }

  while (1)
  {

  }

}
```

The error I have detected is that the waiting time to communicate with the sensor is running out `HAL_I2C_ERROR_TIMEOUT`. I have no idea what a mistake this may be. Do you know what may be happening?

[Configuration in CUBEMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7DyG.png)

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ... 10kΩ is quite a large value for I2C - I'd suggest more like 2.2kΩ. Do you have access to a logic analyser or oscilloscope to check that the STM32's peripheral is actually behaving correctly? (Might also hint at using lower resistors)

Comment: Also, have you configured the pin muxing, so that `PB8` and `PB9` are connected to the I2C peripheral? Look into "_Alternate Functions_" in the STM32's datasheet.

Comment: Also, note that by setting `SDO` high, the device's I2C address is now `0x19`, but I think the `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady()` function expects this to be left shifted once.